# Active Record find method with select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select, find

I can't seem to get this one right at the moment.

I want distinct records but I need other attributes to come along with the results of the find method. Current nonworking code is:

```
Visit.find(:all, :select => "user_id, DISTINCT cookie")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write all the columns you need within the :select

```
Visit.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT cookie, user_id")
```

But this will give the unique combination of the cookie and user_id

like

```
cookie  user_id
1          1
1          2
2          1
2          2
```

But if you want only two cookie i don't think you can do it with Rails find and :select alone. Also if you want though which will come in place of 'x' in above example.

```
cookie  user_id
1          x
2          x
```